# Rerendering the sibling of a react component

Tags: reactjs

I am pretty new to React and I am currently using it to build the frontend of my fullstack web app. I have built a rest api in node/express and use axios to make requests towards it. Users can create rsa keypairs, manage them, save public keys from other users and use them for encryption, decryption and other actions.

On one of my web pages, I have the following components:

- KeysPage (parent)
- KeysList (child)
- GenerateKey (child)

KeysList will fetch the users keys from the database and display them, the user may also delete keys from this component, and it will rerender the list as the state changes. All good here.

I also implemented the possibility to generate new keys from the GenerateKey component, but here I was having trouble forcing the sibling component KeysList to rerender and display the new keypair.

What I ended up doing is passing down as props a function from the common parent down to GenerateKey. This changes a state in the parent that is also passed down as props to KeysList. Now when this change changes, KeysList is also rerendered and updated.

So I was wondering, is this ok or normal to do? It feels like a trick to me, and i couldn't find anything online. Do people use stuff like context for things like these? I felt like implementing a context for just 1 case was not really worth it.

I have not provided any screenshots or code, not sure if it's necessary, I think i explained everything.

Comment: Add the code as well for better understanding. A codesandbox will also work.

Comment: This is a common technique. https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html